# Поиск и замена preg_replace в цикле из массива

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеется такой скрипт который должен найти соответствующие слова из текста и заменить их на нужные.
К примеру найти слова:

- мосвка - заменить на **москва**
- итнернет - заменить на **интернет**  и т.п.

У меня такой код и хочется чтобы в цикле найти и заменить значение из массива

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$matn = $_POST['matn'];
$text =  preg_replace('/\bмосвка\b/imu', 'москва', $matn);
$text =  preg_replace('/\bитнернет\b/imu', 'интернет', $text);
$text =  preg_replace('/\bитиҳод\b/imu', 'иттиҳод', $text);
$text =  preg_replace('/руз/im', 'рӯз', $text);

}
  

?>
```

Comment: отлично подойдет функция https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtr

Comment: что мешает выполнить этот код в цикле?

Comment: там слово слишком много. Поэтому хотелось чтобы все слова хранились в массиве

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, суть скрипта в коррекции ввода данных, для этого подойдет функция [strtr()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtr):

```
$phrases = [
    'моксва'=>'москва',
    'геледнжик'=>'геленджик',
    '\bруз\b'=> 'рус',
];

echo strtr('моксва', $phrases) . "\n";
echo strtr('моксва - руз столица, зато в геледнжике много воды', $phrases) . "\n";

//москва
//москва - руз столица, зато в геленджике много воды
```

Пример с регуляркой:

```
$string = 'моксва - руз столица, зато в геледнжике много воды';

foreach($phrases as $key => $item) {
    $string = preg_replace('~' . $key .'~isu' , $item, $string);
}

echo $string;
//москва - рус столица, зато в геленджике много воды
```

в работе https://3v4l.org/Zj0nm

Comment: Спасибо подойдёт, но в некоторых словах используется регулярные выражение. Как быт в таком случае? К примеру:
'/\bруз\b/imu'

Comment: @Нуримаърифат дополнил

Comment: Спасибо. Отлично работает!